# How to find X11/extensions/XTest.h

Tags: ubuntu, x11

I am using ubuntu 10.10, and when i compile chromium, it said 
`remoting/host/event_executor_linux.cc:9: fatal error: X11/extensions/XTest.h: No such file or directory`

But i have already installed libx11-dev:

```
$ sudo apt-get install  libx11-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libx11-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Please tell me how can I fix my problem.

Thank you.

Comment: libX11 is the core X protocol library - anything under X11/extensions is generally one of the extension libraries.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Install `libxtst-dev` package and you'll be able to compile Chromium sources.

Comment: Note: the package name might not be exactly the same. On the Fedora 16 I had to do: `sudo yum install libXtst-devel`

Comment: This helps compile keepassx, as well.

Comment: easystroke also requires this. nice tip.

Comment: I still had issues in finding this header file in RHEL6.2. I had to do "sudo yum install libXi-devel" to fix it. Got the hint from here: https://code.google.com/p/box2d/issues/detail?id=127

Comment: Also helped with compiling [NEURON](https://neuron.yale.edu/neuron/) on Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: npm module `robotjs` also requires this. Thanks.

Answer (score 50):

To find to which package your include file (`X11/extensions/XTest.h`) belong to, install `apt-file` and search for it, example:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apt-file
$ sudo apt-file update
$ apt-file search "X11/extensions/XTest.h"
libxtst-dev: /usr/include/X11/extensions/XTest.h
```

Once you've the package name, install via:

```
sudo apt-get install libxtst-dev
```

This method is especially useful when there are more similar dependencies like that, so you don't have to guess.